# npm install suddenly not working after trying to update gatsby-cli

Tags: npm, gatsby, node-gyp, apple-silicon

this is going to be a tricky one to explain because so much has gone wrong all at once. I was working on a Gatsby site and decided to update `gatsby-cli`, so I typed (if I remember right) something like `npm update -g gatsby` (which isn't the right command). I got a message to the effect that about 800 packages had been deleted. When I tried running `gatsby develop`, the `gatsby` command was no longer recognised. Then I realised `npm` itself had been wiped. So I ran `brew install node` and managed to reinstall `npm` and `gatsby-cli`. But I've been trying to get the development server up and running again for hours to no avail.

Unfortunately it's hard to be very specific about what's going wrong, because I'm getting so many different error messages. For context, I'm using an M1 (Apple silicon) Mac with Node running natively. I encountered some problems with installing `gatsby-plugin-sharp` specifically, which seemed linked to my install of Xcode. There also seem to be issues with `node-sass`, which is where I'm currently at.

Right now, if I try running `npm install` in the directory of my Gatsby site, I get hundreds of lines of errors, [which I've copied here](https://gist.github.com/finmoorhouse/2dda87a88c26cbc466f427fcd3991cd9).

I've already tried without success:

- Reinstalling Xcode
- Deleting `package_lock.json`
- Clearing the npm cache
- Installing Gatsby 2 rather than Gatsby 3

All the other Gatsby sites on my machine are throwing similar errors. Sorry this is such a vague question, and happy to supply more details. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling your node probably causes this.
it seems like node-gyp is giving you problems with your node version, You can try using https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm and downgrade your node version.

I still run my gatsby v3 sites on node v.12 and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I used NVM to downgrade to Node v12, and after reinstalling `sharp` I managed to get things working again.